# naiveBayes and predict function not working in R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, predict, naivebayes

I am doing a sentiment analysis on twitter comments (in Kazakh language) using below R script. 3000 (1500sad, 1500happy) comments for the training set and 1000 (happy sad mixed) comments for the test set.  Everything works great but at the end, the predicted values are showing all happy, which is not right.

I have checked every function and all are working up until the `naiveBayes` function. I checked classifier values and they are correct.  I think either `naiveBayes` or `predict` is messing things up.

When I used only one happy comment (first on the list) and 1500 sad(negative) comments as training set with this code, predicted results are all happy, which I think should have been sad mostly.

```
classifier = naiveBayes(mat[1500:3000,], as.factor(sentiment_all[1500:3000]))
```

However, when I used all sad or negative comments for the training set, the predicted results are all sad.

```
classifier = naiveBayes(mat[1501:3000,], as.factor(sentiment_all[1501:3000]))
```

I spent hours and I am completely lost where the problem is. Please help me to solve this issue.

Here is the script:

```
setwd("Path")
happy = readLines("Path")
sad = readLines("Path")
happy_test = readLines("Path")
sad_test = readLines("Path")

tweet = c(happy, sad)
tweet_test= c(happy_test, sad_test)
tweet_all = c(tweet, tweet_test)
sentiment = c(rep("happy", length(happy) ), 
              rep("sad", length(sad)))
sentiment_test = c(rep("happy", length(happy_test) ), 
                   rep("sad", length(sad_test)))
sentiment_all = as.factor(c(sentiment, sentiment_test))

library(RTextTools)
library(e1071)

# naive bayes
mat= create_matrix(tweet_all, language="kazakh", 
                   removeStopwords=FALSE, removeNumbers=TRUE, 
                   stemWords=FALSE, tm::weightTfIdf)

mat = as.matrix(mat)

classifier = naiveBayes(mat[1:3000,], as.factor(sentiment_all[1:3000]))
predicted = predict(classifier, mat[3001:4000,]); predicted
```

Comment: No one to comment?

Comment: I suspect predict() function is not working properly.  When I ran  `code` predicted = predict(classifier, mat[1:1,] , type="raw"); predicted `code`  it returns `code`        happy sad
  [1,]   0.5 0.5 `code`  which means predict function is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is very basic, you are setting up your problem wrong. Ideally you want a 50-50 split of positives and negatives for your training data. Because of how the Naive Bayes classifier works, it is trying to minimize entropy.

I am guessing that in your case where you have only 1 positive comment, the classifier was able to minimize entropy very easily based on multiple predictors.

Where you use absolutely no positive comments, you are basically saying that the only predicted value/ the only possible outcome is "sad" and that is exactly what your model is doing.

As for your main issue, try a different using a different data set. 
Where are you getting your tweets from, are they sufficiently diverse?

Comment: Initially I tried with 50-50 split, 1500 happy and 1500 sad comments for training data and it didnt work.   I am following instructions from this source http://datascienceplus.com/sentiment-analysis-with-machine-learning-in-r/.   It works perfectly with their data, but when I replace their data with my Kazakh language comments it simply stops working.  I suspect it is a language issue.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? I think it is likely that your data set is biased someway. Naive Bayes tends to do that. Can you post the result of you ROC curve?

Comment: How do get ROC curve?  Are you sure it is not the language issue?  my data looks like this

Comment: Try this guide http://www.r-bloggers.com/illustrated-guide-to-roc-and-auc/ . I don't know about the language but I think it is unlikely and it is the hardest to diagnose. Lets attempt the easier resolves first. Also, can you describe the data? As in what are the sources of the tweets? How have they been collected?