# Sentiment analysis in foreign language (R language)

Tags: r, comments, sentiment-analysis

I tried doing a sentiment analysis in Kazakh language using RTextTools and e1071 packages in R.  I tried so hard but it is not working and I even posted a question here but no one answered.

Now I am in a point where I think RTextTools and/or e1071 works for only specific languages that it comes with.  I googled it but could not find anything.

Can some one tell me if I can use RTextTools and e1071 packages for foreign language sentiment analysis?   Are there any other ways in R that I could do the analysis?

Here is my previous post:
[naiveBayes and predict function not working in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643592/naivebayes-and-predict-function-not-working-in-r)

Comment: I'd suggest you don't rephrase and repost your query like this, it is a bad practice. I have answered your question in your previous post.

Comment: noted.  I dont see your answer there.  Does it takes some time to show up

Comment: Try refreshing your page.